# Add to python list without quotations

Tags: python, json

How can I add to my python list without quotations that cause a json error?

```
classes["class1"] = "{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}"
```

Thats what I get:

```
  'class1': "{
      'key1': 1,
      'key2': 2,
      'key3': 3
  }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the string `"{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}"` to a dictionary.

```
In [16]: import ast                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [17]: classes = {}                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [18]: classes["class1"] = ast.literal_eval("{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}")                                                                                                                      

In [19]: classes                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[19]: {'class1': {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}}
```

Note that you cannot use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) here due to the single quotes in your string

```
In [20]: import json                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [21]: classes = {}                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [22]: classes["class1"] = json.loads("{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}")                                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-592615e01642> in <module>
----> 1 classes["class1"] = json.loads("{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}")

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: 
line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast 

classes["class1"] = ast.literal_eval("{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}")
```

Comment: Please provide such information or explanation for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> def print_sameline():
...     list = [1,2,3]
...     print("List: ",end="")
...     print(*list,sep=",")
... 
>>> print_sameline()
List: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
classes={}
classes["class1"] = json.loads("{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}".replace("'",'"'))
print(classes["class1"])
```